# Powerpc apps on a MacBook Pro with OS X 10.9

Tags: powerpc, macos

I have several Power PC apps that will no longer work with OS X 10.9.

How can I remove them from my MAC?

Comment: Unless you have a virtual machine or plan on dual booting with Snow Leopard (last OS with Power PC apps support) you have no use for those PPC apps so delete them as you wish.

Answer (score 3):

Well obviously, yes you can. Why would you keep them ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that nobody has actually bothered to read the question properly. The poster wishes to know HOW to remove the apps. The answer in most cases is to simply drag the apps to the trash. There may be some left over preference files but these will generally do no harm.

Comment: If you look at my edit, I probably made part of the other answer obsolete. Thanks for stepping up and giving the pragmatic answer to place the unused apps in the trash.

Answer (score 2):

I've used http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/ for years and it works a treat at removing all the files associated with an app in addition to the app itself (but you do have the choice about which of those files you remove).

For all the great things about OS X, other OSs definitely have it beat when it comes to uninstalling stuff.